# Large text file: Fails to convert one character into another in python

Tags: python

I'm pretty new to Python and want to convert one character into another character in a large string .txt file.

I tried running the following code on shell:

```
#Takes text in letter and converts it
old_text = open("letter.txt", "r")

#Convert old_text to new_text replacing all instances of "a" or into "u"
new_text = old_text.upper().replace("a", "u")
print new_text
```

However, it returns the error "NameError: name 'old_text' is not defined"

Is there anything else I should do to fix this or am I missing something big here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, open() returns a file handle; you need to read the file from the handle if you want a string.

Then you're upper casing the whole string and searching for a lower case letter, which will never replace anything.

Unless there's part of your code that isn't here, it's unclear to me what's resulting in that error.

Comment: I thought I was reading the txt file by including "r" in that line: open("letter.txt", "r").

Comment: You're telling Python that you're opening the file for reading (which is good). But you still need to read from the file handle returned by open(). http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex15.html

Comment: Thanks!  That actually worked!  What I ended up doing is writing: new_text = old_text.read().replace("a","u"). I'd upvote you but I'm one point shy from doing that. Quick follow-up: instead of running the code on shell and IDLE, how could I revise my code to just take an operation and file name directly from the command line?

Comment: You're welcome! Please feel free to mark the answer accepted. If I'm understanding your question correctly, the first example in the learnpythonthehardway link from my comment above is a script that prompts for command line input of the file name.